# How to deal with date changes in pause until workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, designer, pause

i had created a workflow where i had due date workflow will trigger email notification to user post 7 days of due date but what about if i user change due date between this as workflow will not accept new change date and it will remain pause until first due date  in screenshot i am adding minutes to check email trigger this will number of days in real scenario

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the new loop feature to periodically check if a date is within range.

Something like this (short pause, for testing):
[image]

You could also refer to this:

http://sharepointdeveloperblog.blogspot.com/2016/10/pause-until-date-workflows-handle.html

Comment: Thanks its working , i will modify it as per my requirement